# Google Analytics API -> Adwords Keyword data

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-ads-api

I am looking for a way to get keyword data from google Adwords clicks. I know I might get keyword data and more by with the Adwords API using the gclid and the CLICK_PERFORMANCE_REPORT. I haven't tried this yet but I will.
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports#click

This is about data from my client campaigns, and I already have an access_token from my clients to access their Google Analytics account. I prefer not to also have them give our web application access to their Adwords Account.

My question is whether it is also possible to get access to the CLICK_PERFORMANCE_REPORT, or similar information, via the analytics API? The analytics accounts are connected with the clients Adwords account, I just prefer not to also ask them for access to their Adwords account.

So what I would like to achieve is log a visit from Adwords (on my clients' site  to our database) and then (probably once per day) add keyword and campaign data to this. This while circumventing to ask access to my clients Adwords accounts.

Comment: Do you use R? if so i can show you how to connect R and get data through the Rgoogle analytic's package, you can pull the following dimentions:https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#cats=adwords

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to use R, here is a following piece of code that gets Adwords data from GA:

```
library(RGoogleAnalytics)
library(httpuv)

oauth_token <- Auth(client.id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                    client.secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX") # you need to get these from google
save(oauth_token,file="C:/Users/yschellekens.INTRANET/Desktop/Arrow electronics/using the developers API/token_file")
load("C:/Users/yschellekens.INTRANET/Desktop/Arrow electronics/using the developers API/token_file")

Profile<-GetProfiles(oauth_token)

query.visitors <- Init(start.date = "2014-06-01",
                   end.date = "2015-02-01",
                   dimensions = c("ga:fullReferrer","ga:referralPath","ga:keyword"),
                   metrics = c("ga:organicSearches"),
                   max.results = 10000,
                   table.id = "ga:52582227")

# Create the Query Builder object so that the query parameters are validated

# Extract the data and store it in a data-frame
ga.visitors <- GetReportData(QueryBuilder(query.visitors), oauth_token)
table(ga.visitors$hasSocialSourceReferral)
```

For more info on the metrics, see the following:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#cats=adwords

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I don't know R but I guess I could use the queries with the php library. What I don't see though is whether this code grabs Adwords data for a specific gclid.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don't know what gclid is :(

Comment: its a 'google click id' that identifies each click coming in from adwords.

Comment: Looking at the api (and also from my knolage), i dont think you cant grap a specific click in Adwords/GA, you can only get aggregated counts per day

Comment: Thanks. I might try another approach. Maybe I can do something using custom dimensions. I would add a custom id to each visit logged in analytics and I could later use this to retreive adwords information for this visit only using the click_performance_report. What do you think?